# why is a @ symbol required for some DateTime objects in php

Tags: php, datetime

When creating a DateTime object with a unix timestamp, why does a '@' symbol need to precede the time stamp?

Comment: Because [that's what the documentation for supported date/time formats says](http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php). If you are creating a DateTime from a timestamp, the parser has to somehow identify that input as a timestamp as opposed to one of the other supported formats (for example, "120837" is a valid way to express "12:08:37" and if timestamps didn't require a unique identifier "@", you would not be able to definitively determine if the user wanted to express "12:08:37" or the time corresponding to unix timestamp 120837).

Comment: An example is:  new DateTime('@'.$timestamp).    If i create a DateTime object using a unix timestamp without a '@' infront, it fails

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know it is so that the timestamp can be identified from other valid formats.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

unix timestamp is under the compound formats.

Answer (score 1):

It's been quite long since the question is asked, but if anyone still looking for the answer and landed on this question. Then here's it is.

#### Using '@' symbol

```
echo date("dS M Y \\@\\ g:ia");
// 18th Jun 2020 @ 4:20pm
```

#### Using 'at' text

```
echo date("dS M Y \\a\\t g:ia");
// 18th Jun 2020 at 4:20pm
```

#### Using 'and' text

```
echo date("dS M Y \\a\\n\\d g:ia");
// 18th Jun 2020 and 4:20pm
```